# If c ∈ Σ denotes terminals, then is Y = Σ∖{c} the set of non-terminals?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, notation

If $c\in \Sigma$ denotes terminals, then is $Y=\Sigma \setminus \{c\}$ the set of non-terminals?

These notations are used [here](https://books.google.fi/books?id=0Ba3CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA379&lpg=PA379&dq=is%20regular%20if%20only%20if%20right%20linear%20proof&source=bl&ots=0_la-NSYvv&sig=yU6habLgx8RZkpv8asC-tqyyeVI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZ2MCFl7zJAhWFkSwKHZCSAlY4ChDoAQgZMAA#v=onepage&q=is%20regular%20if%20only%20if%20right%20linear%20proof&f=false), p. 379. But I cannot find their definitions.

So what I'm asking is, is the above a reasonable interpretation?

Answer (score 4):

No. $\Sigma$ is the set of symbols that the strings in the two languages are over ("the alphabet"). So $c$ is one symbol, and $Y$ is the set of all the other symbols in the alphabet. These will *all* be terminals when the CFG is constructed in the proof.

What the theorem is saying is that if you have a context-free language $L$ that uses only symbols from $Y$, then $L$ is also regular if and only if the new language where you prepend a $c$ to every string in $L$ (i.e. $cL$) is also regular.

At this point there's no mention of a CFG, so there's no terminals or nonterminals. The proof is where the CFG is introduced as a consequence of $L$ being context-free. Note however that this proof is very very truncated, there's a lot of detail and reasoning left out, so it's a lot harder to follow than it should be if you don't already see the reason that the theorem is true. There's also a series of mistakes in it.